# Verify if a topic exists based on topic name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to verify if a topic exists based on topic name.

Do you know if this is possible?

For example I want to verify if topic with name "test" already exist.

Below is what I'm trying but doesn't work because topicsList contains topicArns and not topicNames...

```
topics = sns.get_all_topics()   
topicsList = topics['ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult'['Topics']

if "test" in topicsList:
    print("true")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a hack but it should work:

```
topics = sns.get_all_topics()   
topic_list = topics['ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult']['Topics']
topic_names = [t['TopicArn'].split(':')[5] for t in topic_list]

if 'test' in topic_names:
   print(True)
```

Comment: That won't work if you only have permission to publish on the topic and not ListTopics permission

Answer (score 5):

What if you try to catch `An error occurred (NotFound) when calling the GetTopicAttributes operation: Topic does not exist` exception?

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:999999999:neverFound"

try:
    response = client.get_topic_attributes(
        TopicArn=topic_arn
    )
    print "Exists"
except ClientError as e:
    # Validate if is this:
    # An error occurred (NotFound) when calling the GetTopicAttributes operation: Topic does not exist
    print "Does not exists"
```

Comment: You can also capture `client.exceptions.NotFoundException` when using boto3

Answer (score 4):

This code will work if you have more than 100 topics

```
def get_topic(token=None):
    topics = self.sns.get_all_topics(token)
    next_token = topics['ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult']['NextToken']
    topic_list = topics['ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult']['Topics']
    for topic in topic_list:
        if "your_topic_name" in topic['TopicArn'].split(':')[5]:
            return topic['TopicArn']
    else:
        if next_token:
            get_topic(next_token)
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: This only works if you declare the get_topic method as part of a class, right? Otherwise how is 'self' passed (apologies if this is a dumb question)

Comment: @Alex Glover yes you are correct, I c&p this from a class