# Boto is only deleting 100 entry of SNS Topic and Not all

Tags: boto, amazon-sns

I have 700 SNS topic in my account. I am deleting all of them using boto. The code is deleting them but i see only 100 topics are deleted everytime. I have run code 7 times to delete all 700 topics. I want all of them to be deleted at one go

Tried GUI also manually but same issue

```
def delete_topic(self, topic):
        params = {'ContentType' : 'JSON',
                  'TopicArn' : topic}
        response = self.make_request('DeleteTopic', params, '/', 'GET')
        body = response.read()
        if response.status == 200:
            return json.loads(body)
        else:
            boto.log.error('%s %s' % (response.status, response.reason))
            boto.log.error('%s' % body)
            raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)

endpoint = boto.sqs.regioninfo.RegionInfo(name=region,endpoint='sns.'+str(region)+'.amazonaws.com')

sns = boto.connect_sns(aws_access_key_id=aKey, aws_secret_access_key=aSecret,region=endpoint)

topics = sns.get_all_topics()

dict_topic = topics[u'ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult']['Topics']

i=0

for  key in  dict_topic:
    topic=topics[u'ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult']['Topics'][i]['TopicArn']
    delete_topic(sns,topic)
    print "Deleted the topic"+str(topic)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Side-note: It appears that you are using `boto`. These days, it is better to use `boto3`. See: https://github.com/boto/boto3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the next_token paramater since its a nested dict paginated:

```
get_all_topics(next_token=None)                                           
     Parameters:    next_token (string) – Token returned by the previous call to this method.
```

[Boto v2 documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/sns.html)

Also you can check this post out:

[Verify if a topic exists based on topic name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243687/verify-if-a-topic-exists-based-on-topic-name)